# UPDATE/SET/OUTPUT/FROM with output into variable

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Consider the following stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AssignCodeToCustomer (@customerId int)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @code NVARCHAR(255)

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        SELECT @code = (
            UPDATE
                Codes
            SET
                CustomerId = @customerId
            OUTPUT
                INSERTED.Code
            FROM (
                SELECT TOP 1
                    Code
                FROM
                    Codes
            ) AS c
            WHERE
                c.Code = Codes.Code

        -- Other stuff

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

            EXEC spLogSQLError
        END
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

I get an error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword `UPDATE`' on line 10 (which holds the keyword `UPDATE`). I could also first select a code and then assign it, but with concurrency in mind I want only one query. The query works if I don't try to set the output value into the variable. How can I fix this error or should I use another approach?

Comment: You can't capture the value(s) from  `OUTPUT` into a scalar variable for obvious reasons, `OUTPUT` can produce multiple columns and rows, a scalar variable holds a single value. If you want to capture the records output, you need to do so in a table variable.

Comment: but as `TOP 1` guarantees at most a single row you can just assign to the variable directly inside the `UPDATE` with no need for any nesting. `UPDATE TOP (1) Codes
                    SET
                CustomerId = @customerId,
    @code = Code
                FROM
                    Codes` assuming you just want an arbitrary `TOP` - you might need a sub query if you want an `ORDER BY` applied

Comment: @Larnu [An update statement can be in a subquery](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=11a20d7df850e60298020d46f7939a98), but [the subquery can only be a source of an insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#inserting-data-returned-from-an-output-clause-into-a-table), it cannot be used to assign variables in the manner the OP has tried.

Comment: Huh, that's some janky syntax there, @GarethD , but you're right.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I don't need any ordering, so your suggestion works for me. Thank you. If you add an answer, I can mark it as the accepted answer for my question.

Comment: I'm busy at the moment I'll add an answer some point later if no one beats me to it!